# How Filter Objects what contains in FK?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I have three Models, like Store, ProductsArea and Item. A Store can have many ProductsArea, and ProductsArea can have many Items.

```
    #models.py
    class Store(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class ProductArea(models.Model):
        store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='productarea', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64,verbose_name=_('Name'))

    class Item(models.Model):
        product_area = models.ForeignKey(ProductArea, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Menu')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=_('Name'))
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Price'))
```

In my view I'm using CBV, and I want return all Items what contains the same ProductArea, clicking  ListItems from determined ProductArea, with FK they get all items from ProductArea. The same for ProductArea in Store.

```
Store - Clothes Store
Product Area - Shirts, Pants
Item - Shirt Yellow(PA.Shirts), Shirt Blue(PA.Shirts)
Item - Pant Black(PA.Pants), Pants Red(PA.Pants)
```

If a click in `Shirts`, I want return a list with a `Shirt Yellow` and a `Shirt Blue`.

I tried this in my view :

```
def get_queryset(self):
    product_area_id = ProductArea.objects.get(id)
    product_area = ProductArea.objects.get(pk=product_area_id)
    items_in_productarea = Item.objects.filter(product_area=product_area)
    return items_in_productarea
```

But doesn't work,have `builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lof friends.

Comment: Well first of all `id` is *not* the `id` of the URL (please post your relevant `url` as well), it is the identity function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use [**`id`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). Now `id` is a *builtin* Python function: it maps all objects to a number that is unique. It is used for example to check if two variables refer to the *same* object. The details of `id` are not really important here, the point is that `id` is *not* the `id` here in the URL.

You will need to fetch the `id` from somewhere, for example it can be part of the URL. We can specify it in the `urls.py`:

```
#  app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('items/<int:area_id>/', MyItemView.as_view(), name='my_item_view')
]
```

I would advice to use an `area_id` here instead of `id` since otherwise it might give the (false) impression that it is the `id` of the `Item`s.

Then we can process the URL parameter with `self.kwargs`:

```
#  app/views.py

from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from app.models import Item

class MyItemView(ListView):

    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Item.objects.filter(product_area__id=self.kwargs['area_id'])
```

If you the fetch `localhost:8000/items/123` (with `123` the idea of the `ProductArea`, the URL can be different if for example the `app/urls.py` are included in a non-empty path), you will get a list of `Item`s that belong in this `ProductArea`.

Comment: Nice solution, and great explanation...it's works, I got it and will apply in other things in my project. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Please, select the answer as the correct answer if it is the solution. Thanks.